# Thymeleaf - Appending <br> to input tag

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'm trying to append a `<br>` after every input line in a form, but Thymeleaf keeps giving me parsing error.

Here is the code piece that I'm having trouble with:

```
<form th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(brands)}">
<input th:each="brand : ${brands}" type="checkbox" th:value="${brand.name}" th:utext="${brand.name + <br>}" />
</form>
```

If I add the `<br>` tag outside of input tag, it doesn't add it to each line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't <br> be in quotation marks? I don't know thymeleaf, but it seems weird to me that <br> is not between " "

Comment: Are you saying `th:utext="${brand.name}" + "<br>"`? If yes, this is a syntax error in Thymeleaf.

Comment: I meant th:utext="${brand.name + '<br>'}"

Comment: That doesn't work either. Same parsing error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be going about this in the wrong way.

[`th:utext`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text) would insert that *within* the `<input>` node. But, according to the [HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element), nothing goes in an `<input>` tag ("Content model: Empty.")

I think you want something more like this:

```
<form th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(brands)}">
    <th:block th:each="brand : ${brands}">
        <label th:for="${#ids.next('brand')}" th:text="${brand.name}">Brand A</label>
        <input type="checkbox" th:id="${#ids.seq('brand')}"
            name="brand" th:value="${brand.name}"/>
        <br/>
    </th:block>
</form>
```

If you're using Spring MVC, you may also find this example helpful: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#checkbox-fields

Comment: This code gives me an error at ${#ids.next('brand')}, but other than that it fixed the br issue. Thanks for the link to that example.

Comment: Oops, I think I was missing a `}` ... try the edited version.