# how to add new line in thymeleaf between two strings in java?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'm beginner in Thymeleaf.

I want to add br tag in between two strings
in html

Ex:
I want to add break tag in between ${student[0] and ${student[1].
${student[1] data should come to the next line.

th:text="|${student[0]} br ${student[1]}|"

.Can anyone help me? Any comments would be appreciate Thanks in advance....

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127593/thymeleaf-appending-br-to-input-tag) is what you are looking for

Comment: No, I'm looking such type of model

Comment: What do you mean by "No, I'm looking such type of model " what model????

Comment: No, I'm not looking such type of example

Comment: alright then I guess you don't want help

Comment: Bro It's not like that , I did not mean like I mentioned I don't want such type of example

Answer (score 5):

You can use `th:utext` to output html, like this

```
th:utext="|${student[0]} <br /> ${student[1]}|"
```

That said, I would stay away from that if possible and just add it as regular html, like this for example:

```
<span th:text="${student[0]}">
<br />
<span th:text="${student[1]}">
```