# Thymeleaf template parsing error with linebreak

Tags: spring-boot, templates, kotlin, thymeleaf, email-templates

This is my current template that is throwing an error

```
<div th:inline="text">[#th:block th:each="i: ${application.premises}"] <br/> [[${i.streetName}]]  [/th:block]</div>
```

This works:

```
<div th:inline="text">
    [# th:each="i : ${application.premises}"] [[${i.streetName}]] [/]
</div>
```

However, when i try to add a `<br/>` it throws an error. What i am trying to do is add a linebreak after every street name is printed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thymeleaf - Appending <br> to input tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127593/thymeleaf-appending-br-to-input-tag)

Comment: Not really. I wanna use the inline styling and add a <br> instead

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `<div />` to get your linebreaks in the first place, rather than trying to put `<br />`s in a text template? There is really no reason to be using the text template mode in this case:

For example:

```
<div th:each="i: ${application.premises}" th:text="${i.streetName}" />
```

or

```
<th:block th:each="i: ${application.premises}">
  <span th:text="${i.streetName}" />
  <br />
</th:block>
```

Comment: Because we want to simplify the syntax for the users and did not want them to be typing in html. Are you aware of any solution to  add in the linebreak/<br/>? Thank you

Comment: No, I couldn't see any way to do that.